# Java HashMap and underlying values() collection

Tags: java, hashmap

I was wondering if the Collection view of the values contained in a HashMap is kept ordered when the HashMap changes.

For example if I have a HashMap whose values() method returns L={a, b, c}
What happened to L if I add a new element "d" to the map?
Is it added at the end, i.e. if I iterate through the elements, it's the order kept?

In particular, if the addition of the new element "d" causes a rehash, will the order be kept in L?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> **I was wondering if the Collection view of the values contained in a HashMap is kept ordered when the HashMap changes.**

No, there is no such guarantee.

If this was the case, then the following program would output and ordered sequence from 1-100

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    map.put(i, i);

System.out.println(map.values());
```

([and it doesn't)](http://ideone.com/n9yjE).

There is a class that does precisely what you're asking for, and that is `LinkedHashMap`:

> *Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. **This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map** (insertion-order).*

Comment: @TofuBeer, Are you sure? You read through the entire sequence? Which runtime are you using?

Comment: Change it to <String, Integer> and put(Integer.toString(i) and you will see it not being ordered.  But then, if you print out the values after each insertion, you will find that the order remains stable (which, depending on how you read the question is what is being asked, not the original insertion order maintained).

Comment: Whoops - I shortened the length of the input to test the above one and it wound up being the same - at 100 it is different.

Comment: I should not comment when I am sick I think... back to be with me :-)

Comment: You selected not the best example, as `new Integer(i).hashCode() == i`, and thus the buckets are used nearly one-by-one.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann. Thats right. With strings for instance, it's even "less" ordered. I chose integers because it is easy to spot if one element is out of order. Perhaps I should have done `"" + i` or something :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't say it in the JavaDoc then there are no guarantees about it.  Different versions of Java could do different things.  Don't depend on undocumented behaviour.

You might want to look at [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap in Java aren't ordered**, so I think it will be safe to say that values() won't return an ordered Collection.

[LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is an ordered version of HashMap (insertion order), but I don't know it values() will return an ordered Collection. I think the best is to try.

Comment: I've tried. Neither of them keeps the order of insertion. Interestingly they both return the same Collection with the same order: I suspect it's based on the value of the hashcode() method

Comment: @javaexpert: Could you please post your result with a LinkedHashMap using not insertion order? It should, according to its documentation.  (A normal HashMap's iterator orders the elements by the buckets, which are filled by the result of `hashCode` (modulo the capacity). But this is not specified, it could be any order.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally they is no guarantee of order when you are using HashMap. It might be in the order in which you add elements for a few elements but it would get reshuffled when there is a possibility of collision and it has to go with a collision resolution strategy.